# Set tooltip dynamically in HIGHCHARTS

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

Am using Highcharts in my application. Here, am facing one problem like,

My x-axis list is,

```
var peMList = ["EM", "UF", "WT"];
```

My Object like,

```
var mapObj = {};
mapObj["EM"]="Element_Missing";
mapObj["UF"]="Unknown_Format";
mapObj["WT"]="Wrong_Type";
```

My chart Format like,

```
tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>'+mapObj['{point.key}'],
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}% </b><br/>',
        shared: true
    }
```

How can I add my object value in my chart tooltip. **I already added But, its showing undefined.**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `formatter` function:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '<span style="font-size:10px">' + this.points[0].key + '</span><table>' + mapObj[this.points[0].key] + '</table><br/>' + '<span style="color:' + this.points[0].series.color + '">' + this.points[0].series.name + '</span>: <b>' + this.points[0].y + '% </b>'
    },
    shared: true
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jvg0fk7y/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter